# Total Number of Instructions executed in Mips Assembly Program (instr. counter vs instr. stats)

Tags: assembly, count, mips, instructions

to check number of instructions executed in MIPS, there are two options as far as I see. In Tools there is:
1) Instruction Counter
2) Instruction Statistics

when I run these tools on my Program I get off-by-1 result. i.e
example code is:

```
.data

.text
 addiu $t0, $zero, 0
 addiu $t1, $zero, 0
 addiu $t2, $zero, 100

 loop:
    bge $t1, $t2, loop_end
    bge $t1, 0x40, loop_end

andi $t3, $t1, 1    
addiu $t1, $t1, 1
j loop

loop_end:
xor $t0, $t3, $t3
```

with method 1) i get:
[image]

method 2:

[image]

anybody knows where does this difference come from and which one should i take as the correct answer?

Comment: 66 + 326 + 64 = 456

Comment: @prl good point, so how come it makes a simple arithmetic mistake... anyway Ill go with the second one i guess.